# NoSuchElementException | Flipkart/Paytm | Log In/Sign Up

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm simply writing a script to click on the Login/Signup link present on Flipkart/Paytm, but everytime I'm running the script I'm getting no such element exception.

kindly look into the script and help me for the same.

public class Try {

```
WebDriver driver = null;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    String basePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    //System.out.println(basePath);
    String finalPath = basePath + "\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe";
    //System.out.println(finalPath);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", finalPath);
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("http://flipkart.com");
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.close();
}

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("a");
    //Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/div/header/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[7]/a")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Log in")).click();
    System.out.println("hie");
}
```

}

Comment: I see that you are using IE for executing you test, and xpath tends to break for IE browser, I am wondering if same code worked on Firefox and/or Chrome?

Comment: Yes the same code is working in Firefox...I have even tried using Id or Link Text in IE but it's not working..

Comment: Then you can try for CSS selector for IE or for all other browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be very specific about casing while using Link Text. I can see that the Link Text is "Log In" with a capital I.

Use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Log In")).click();
```

Works for me on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, I'm successfully able to do this on Flipkart website:

`login_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Log In')
login_link.click()`

An alternate solution:

If you are not testing the login button itself, you can also directly navigate to `/account/login` page in case of Flipkart (didn't verify for PayTM). The path by its very name seems static and you won't have to worry about getting exact locators for login button on the home page.

Eg: `driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/account/login')`.